# Gradle Javadoc plugin custom task with Doclava invalid flag -link

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, javadoc, doclet, gradle-task

I am adding my custom gradle task in my libraries build.gradle with Doclava implementation as:

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->

task("generateNew${variant.name.capitalize()}Javadoc", type: Javadoc) {
    title = ""

    destinationDir = new File("${project.getProjectDir()}/doc/compiled/", variant.baseName)
    description "Generates Javadoc for $variant.name."
    source = variant.javaCompile.source
    ext.androidJar = "${android.sdkDirectory}/platforms/${android.compileSdkVersion}/android.jar"
    classpath = files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files) + files(ext.androidJar) + project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    options {
        memberLevel = org.gradle.external.javadoc.JavadocMemberLevel.PRIVATE
        links "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/"
        linksOffline "http://d.android.com/reference", "${android.sdkDirectory}/docs/reference"
        doclet = "com.google.doclava.Doclava"
        List<File> pathList = new ArrayList<File>();
        pathList.add(file('./libs/doclava-1.0.6.jar'))
        docletpath = pathList
    }
    exclude '**/BuildConfig.java'
    exclude '**/R.java'
}
```

}

and when I run the task gradle give me the error **javadoc: error - invalid flag: -link**. But the task can be run when I remove the links & linksOffline option. Another problem is the provided PRIVATE member option is not working, the generated document shows only public members.

Is there any way around to fix it so that with the Doclava doclet I can get the reference links to the Android and Java references?